# Лёгкий HTTP server

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, сервер, веб-сервер

Посоветуйте пожалуйста HTTP-сервер для отладки скриптов, встроенный в PHP сервер устраивает почти полностью, но он не понимает htaccess

**Требования:**

- Под **Linux**
- Поддержка **PHP**
- Поддержка **.htaccess**
- Работает **по требованию** (Develop)
- **Маленький**, можно даже микро (в плане расхода памяти)
- **Простой** в настройке

Comment: Как вариант - можете самостоятельно развернуть http сервер, подробная статья по развертке представлена на https://habrahabr.ru/post/69136/

Comment: `.htaccess` - это файл конфигурации Apache Server, а не общий стандарт. А значит, никаких понимающих его серверов вы, скорее всего, не найдете.

Comment: @Legionary, а он точно с PHP работает? В статье нет упоминания об этом

Comment: Php имеет встроенный сервер

Comment: @Steve в вопросе об этом сказано

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lighttpd](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lighttpd) вас устроит? Обычно настроек "из коробки" достаточно.

Comment: только про .htaccess он ничего не знает, но так ли он необходим

Comment: @Smithson, спасибо, буду пробовать, но так как .htaccess-поддержки не может быть значит и решения полноценного нет

Comment: @sercxjo да просто хотелось бы как можно более приближенного окружения к целевому серверу, но без излишних хлопот

Comment: @tonchikp, .htaccess - вещь специфическая для апача, у каждого http-сервера свои особенности конфигурирования.

Comment: @sercxjo я понимаю

Answer (score 4):

Давайте с требований уберем одно - "Маленький, можно даже микро (в плане расхода памяти)". И теперь есть решение - использовать обычный апач в докере. Да, придется написать небольшой скрипт для его запуска, но все решается.

Пройдемся по требованиям

- Под Linux - да, конечно.
- Поддержка PHP - это же обычный апач.
- Поддержка .htaccess - конечно да.
- Работает по требованию (Develop) - да, запуск одной командой (`docker run ....`) и одной закрыть.
- Маленький, можно даже микро (в плане расхода памяти) - в принципе, оно не так много памяти потребляет
- Простой в настройке - если Вы знаете, как настроить апач, то да, он прост в настройке

еще плюсы:

- можно иметь несколько различных версий апача и пхп (иногда это бывает очень нужно)
- очень легко "дать другу" - то есть, перенести на другую машину с сохранением конфигурации - достаточно передать докер-файл.
- не загрязняет рабочую машину лишними файлами (ну кроме докер образом, но они хранятся в одном месте и никому не мешают).
- можно держать сложную конфигурацию. Например, десяток серверов с апачем, несколько баз данных с репликацией, и тому подобное.

По поводу памяти. У меня прямо сейчас на рабочей машине в докере запущен nginx, который тестирует клиентов и обслуживает 300-500 запросов в секунду. При этом он потребляет около 0.1 % памяти (от 8Гб). По беглым подсчетам - чуть больше мегабайта.

Вариант два: использовать отдельно стоящий сервер (можно как действительно "рядом стоящий" - на растоянии вытянутой руки, так и отдельно, в датацентре). Более-менее нормальный минимальный сервер в датацентре будет стоить 5-10 долл/месяц. Для нормального разработчика это допустимые расстраты.

Плюсы:

- сервер реальный.
- обычно доступен всегда - можно оставить показать заказчику и лечь спать - комп не нужно оставлять включенным и не нужно заниматься настройками.
- доступен с различных мест - можно поработать с кафе с левого компьютера.

Comment: спасибо за развёрнутый ответ, часто слышу про Docker, но времени разобраться с этим нет, но как-нибудь чувствую прийду к этому, хорошая вещь

Comment: разбираться там пол часа для начального этапа. установить его с репозитория и запустить `docker run apache`.

Comment: да меня в принципе сам Apache беспокоит, мне кажется для моих маленьких задач это решение очень жирное, хотя и верное

Comment: тогда задам вопрос в лоб - а Вы пробовали померять, сколько реально памяти оно кушает? или Ваши предположение построены исключительно на интернетслухах и собственных страхах?

Comment: в этом вопросе 2 стороны: 1) Жирно в плане наличия огромных возможностей, которые мной использоваться не будут 2) Жирно в плане потребления памяти - действительно интернет слухи, страхи и догадки как вытекающее из первой стороны, ведь за наличие возможностей надо платить, но зачем? Только ради htaccess? Будут большие потребности - конечно это решение будет оптимальным, но сейчас нет

Comment: запустил голый апач - вместе с nginx в отдельном контейнере потребляет около 1% памяти - то есть, около 80 мб. Апач написан достаточно хорошо и лишней памяти он не будет так просто кушать. Не бойтесь интернет слухов, они только тормозят Вас как разработчика.

Comment: Ну не знаю, не подумайте что меня только память интересует, опять же это не отменяет того, что настраивать придётся многие ненужные мне параметры (хотя ставил Apache я очень-очень давно, может сейчас всё кардинально изменилось)

Comment: Когда смотрел, что такое докер, у меня сложилось ощущение, что он платный... Если это так, то странно, что в ответе про это ничего нет. Да и вообще, было бы неплохо уточнить, что там этом плане.

Comment: сам докер бесплатный (более того, с исходным кодом). Платное есть, но это как обычно, поддержка, тренинги (но у них документации бесплатной вагон и тележка). Также компания предоставляет хостинг с поддержкой докера и энтерпрайз решения, но это для больших компаний, которые понимают, что им нужно. Обычному разработчику можно обойтись без этого.